# Rendering tree of nodes as string

Tags: c#, strings, recursion, tree

I'm creating a *debug-view* for my [expression-trees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208332/adjusting-business-logic-conveniently-through-json-and-expression-trees). They *record* each operation automatically in a tree that I am transforming into `string` so that I can see the exact evaluation of expressions.

---

#### Tree(Node)

This tree is represented by the `TreeNode`. It stores the `Value` of the current node and its children.

```
[PublicAPI]
[DebuggerDisplay(DebuggerDisplayString.DefaultNoQuotes)]
public class TreeNode<T> : List<TreeNode<T>>
{
    public TreeNode(T value, IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> children)
        : base(children)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public TreeNode(T value)
        : this(value, Enumerable.Empty<TreeNode<T>>()) { }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => this.ToDebuggerDisplayString(b =>
    {
        b.DisplayValue(x => x.Value);
        b.DisplayValue(x => x.Count);
    });

    [NotNull]
    public static TreeNode<T> Empty => new TreeNode<T>(default);

    [CanBeNull]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(TreeNode<T> node) => node.Value;

    public static implicit operator TreeNode<T>(T value) => new TreeNode<T>(value);
}

public static class TreeNode
{
    public static TreeNode<T> Create<T>(T value) => new TreeNode<T>(value);
}

public static class TreeNodeExtensions
{
    public static (TreeNode<T> Parent, TreeNode<T> Child) Append<T>(this TreeNode<T> parent, T value)
    {
        var child = new TreeNode<T>(value);
        parent.Add(child);
        return (parent, child);
    }
}
```

#### Test data

This *node* when created like this:

```
var root = TreeNode.Create((Person)("John", "Doe"));
root.Append(("Sam", "Doe")).Child.Append(("Tom", "Doe")).Parent.Append(("Juliet", "Doe"));
root.Append(("Vanessa", "Doe"));
```

based on this test model:

> ```
> [DebuggerDisplay(DebuggerDisplayString.DefaultNoQuotes)]
> public class Person
> {
>   private string DebuggerDisplay => this.ToDebuggerDisplayString(b =>
>   {
>       b.DisplayValue(x => x.FirstName);
>   });
>
>   public string FirstName { get; set; }
>
>   public string LastName { get; set; }
>
>   private object ToDump() => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
>
>   public static implicit operator Person((string FirstName, string LastName) p) => new Person
>   {
>       FirstName = p.FirstName,
>       LastName = p.LastName
>   };
> }
> ```

#### Usage example

needs to be renderd as *something*. This *something* is currently a `string`:

```
var renderer = new StringTreeNodeRenderer();
renderer.Render(root, (p, d) => $"ln: {p.LastName}{Environment.NewLine}fn: {p.FirstName} ({d})").Dump("Service");
```

> ```
> ln: Doe
> fn: John (0)
>    ln: Doe
>    fn: Sam (1)
>       ln: Doe
>       fn: Tom (2)
>       ln: Doe
>       fn: Juliet (2)
>    ln: Doe
>    fn: Vanessa (1)
> ```

#### Renderer

The utility that does that is implemented recursively. For DI purposes I use an interface here and in case I should have other renderers later (like json or html). The *default* `StringTreeNodeRenderer` calls the `RenderValueCallback` for each value, indents it appropriately and then turns everything into a single `string`.

```
public delegate string RenderValueCallback<T>(T value, int depth);

public interface ITreeNodeRenderer<TResult>
{
    TResult Render<TValue>(TreeNode<TValue> root, RenderValueCallback<TValue> renderValue);
}

public abstract class TreeNodeRenderer<TResult> : ITreeNodeRenderer<TResult>
{
    public abstract TResult Render<TValue>(TreeNode<TValue> root, RenderValueCallback<TValue> renderValue);
}

public class StringTreeNodeRenderer : ITreeNodeRenderer<string>
{
    public int IndentWidth { get; set; } = 3;

    public string Render<TValue>(TreeNode<TValue> root, RenderValueCallback<TValue> renderValue)
    {
        var nodeViews = Render(root, 0, renderValue);
        var indentedNodeViews = nodeViews.Select(nv => nv.Value.IndentLines(IndentWidth * nv.Depth));
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, indentedNodeViews);
    }

    private IEnumerable<TreeNodeView> Render<T>(TreeNode<T> root, int depth, RenderValueCallback<T> renderValue)
    {
        yield return new TreeNodeView
        {
            Value = renderValue(root, depth),
            Depth = depth
        };

        var views =
            from node in root
            from view in Render(node, depth + 1, renderValue)
            select view;

        foreach (var view in views)
        {
            yield return view;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Helpers

The renderer is using two helper extensions. One for indenting all lines in a `string` an one for trimming a `StringBuilder`.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string IndentLines(this string value, int indentWidth, char indentCharacter = ' ', Encoding encoding = default)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        using (var valueStream = new MemoryStream((encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8).GetBytes(value)))
        using (var valueReader = new StreamReader(valueStream))
        {
            while (valueReader.ReadLine() is var line && line != null)
            {
                output
                    .Append(new string(indentCharacter, indentWidth))
                    .AppendLine(line);
            }
        }

        return 
            output
                .TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine)
                .ToString();
    }
}

public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilder TrimEnd(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, string value)
    {
        var startIndex = stringBuilder.Length - value.Length;
        for (int i = startIndex, j = 0; j < value.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            if (!stringBuilder[i].Equals(value[j]))
            {
                return stringBuilder;
            }
        }

        return 
            stringBuilder
                .Remove(startIndex, value.Length)
                .TrimEnd(value);
    }
}
```

*(The debugger utilities I use here are part of my [Diagnostics](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/tree/dev/Reusable.Core/src/Diagnostics) tools.)*

---

#### Questions

My main questions are:

- Is everything properly separated and encapsulated?
- Is it extendable?
- Is it easy to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the following things to your API:

- let tree items know their parent and children -> easier navigation
- encapsulate the children -> better integrity

As for the rendering, it can be done more lightweight.

sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var root = TreeNode.Create(new Person("John", "Doe"))
            .Add(new Person("Sam", "Doe"))
                .Add(new Person("Tom", "Doe"))
                .Parent.Add(new Person("Juliet", "Doe"))
            .Root.Add(new Person("Vanessa", "Doe"))
            .Root;

        var rendered = Render(root, (p, d) => 
            string.Format("ln: {0}{3}fn: {1} ({2})", p.LastName, p.FirstName, d, Environment.NewLine));

        Console.Write(rendered);
    }

    private static string Render<T>(TreeNode<T> tree, Func<T, int, string> layout) 
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var indent = new Stack<string>();
        var depth = 0;

        RenderTree(builder, tree, depth, layout, indent);

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private static void RenderTree<T>(StringBuilder builder, TreeNode<T> tree, int depth, Func<T, int, string> layout, Stack<string> indent) {

        Render(builder, tree.Value, depth, layout, indent);

        indent.Push("\t");
        depth++;

        foreach (var child in tree.Children) {
            RenderTree(builder, child, depth, layout, indent);
        }

        indent.Pop();
    }

    private static void Render<T>(StringBuilder builder, T element, int depth, Func<T, int, string> layout, Stack<string> indent) {

        var textLines = layout(element, depth).Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var textIndent = string.Join(string.Empty, indent);

        foreach (var textLine in textLines) {
            builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", textIndent, textLine));
        }
    }

    public class TreeNode<T>
    {
        private List<TreeNode<T>> children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();

        public TreeNode(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public static TreeNode<T> Empty { get { return new TreeNode<T>(default(T)); }}

        public T Value { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> Children { get { return children.ToArray(); }}

        public TreeNode<T> Parent { get; private set; }

        public TreeNode<T> Root { get { return Parent == null ? this : Parent.Root; }}

        public static implicit operator T(TreeNode<T> node) { return node.Value; }

        public static implicit operator TreeNode<T>(T value) { return new TreeNode<T>(value); }

        public TreeNode<T> Add(TreeNode<T> child) {
            // TODO check null, check family (is self, ancestor, descendant, or child of other parent) ..
            children.Add(child);
            child.Parent = this;
            return child;
        }

        public TreeNode<T> Remove(TreeNode<T> child) {
            // TODO check null, check family (is child) ..
            if (children.Contains(child)) {
                children.Remove(child);
                child.Parent = null;
            }
            return child;
        }
    }

    public static class TreeNode
    {
        public static TreeNode<T> Create<T>(T value) { return new TreeNode<T>(value); }
    }

    public class Person
    {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }

      public string LastName { get; set; }

      public Person(string firstName, string lastName) {
          FirstName = firstName;
          LastName = lastName;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: These are some interesting ideas! Cool :-)

Comment: Hi man, glad you like the ideas. You can build an even better API by creating generic tree walkers. Your renderer could use a tree walker in depth-first (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) order.

Comment: I knew I might be reinventing the wheel. Implementing a well known method sounds reasonable. I'll give it a try.