# Chaining JSON transformations with visitors

Tags: c#, json, json.net, visitor-pattern

I have currently two use-cases that require JSON transformations before it can be deserialized.

- The first use-case requires changing the custom short type property name from `$t` to `$type` and resolving full type names from their aliases. This is the same as in my [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205940/making-typenamehandling-in-json-net-more-convenient) question.
- The second use-case is about fixing property names that contain whitespaces and need to be trimmed like `> Name   <` instead of `>Name<` (yeah, I've spent quite some time spotting this mistake in a large file recently).

My previous solution supported only resolving type names and was build with a custom `JsonTextReader`. Now that I wanted to add another trasnformation to it, I noticed that it cannot be chained because the reader supports forward-only reading and there is no way to add to it.

I've changed my strategy and used the `JToken.Parse` instead with a couple of visitors that work similar to the `ExpressionVisitor`.

The first one of them is the `JsonVisitor` that recursively rebuilds the tree and allows to intercept this process by overriding `VisitProperty`:

```
public delegate JToken VisitJsonCallback(JToken token);

public class JsonVisitor
{
    public static JToken Visit(JToken token, params JsonVisitor[] visitors)
    {
        return visitors.Aggregate(token, (current, visitor) => visitor.Visit(current));
    }

    public static VisitJsonCallback Create(params JsonVisitor[] visitors) => jToken => Visit(jToken, visitors);

    public JToken Visit(JToken token)
    {
        return
            token is JValue
                ? token
                : VisitInternal(token, CreateJContainer(token.Type));
    }

    private JToken VisitInternal(JToken token, JContainer result)
    {
        if (token is JValue)
        {
            return token;
        }

        foreach (var element in token)
        {
            switch (element)
            {
                case JProperty property:
                    var visitedProperty = VisitProperty(property);
                    result.Add(visitedProperty);
                    break;
                default:
                    result.Add(Visit(element));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected virtual JProperty VisitProperty(JProperty property)
    {
        return new JProperty(property.Name, Visit(property.Value));
    }

    private static JContainer CreateJContainer(JTokenType tokenType)
    {
        switch (tokenType)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object: return new JObject();
            case JTokenType.Array: return new JArray();
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Invalid type: {tokenType}");
        }
    }
}
```

Since I didn't have any other use cases yet, it's the only overridable API right now but I think it should be easy to extend it in future.

Then I have two more of them that cover both use-cases (here in the reverse order)

```
public class PropertyNameTrimmer : JsonVisitor
{
    protected override JProperty VisitProperty(JProperty property)
    {
        return new JProperty(property.Name.Trim(), Visit(property.Value));
    }
}

public class TypeResolver : JsonVisitor
{
    private readonly string _typePropertyName;
    private readonly Func<string, string> _resolveType;

    public TypeResolver(string typePropertyName, Func<string, string> resolveType)
    {
        _typePropertyName = typePropertyName;
        _resolveType = resolveType;
    }

    protected override JProperty VisitProperty(JProperty property)
    {
        return
            property.Name == _typePropertyName
                ? new JProperty("$type", _resolveType(property.Value.Value<string>()))
                : base.VisitProperty(property);
    }
}
```

---

#### Example

I would use them by passing the result from one to the other:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{ ""$t"": ""MyType"", ""User  "": ""John"", ""Nested"": { ""$t"": ""OtherType"", ""   ZIP"": 12345 }, ""Numbers"": [1, 2, 3 ] }";

    var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);
    jToken.ToString().Dump("Original");    

    var propertyNameTrimmer = new PropertyNameTrimmer();
    var typeResolver = new TypeResolver("$t", shortName => shortName + "_resolved");

    var trimmed = propertyNameTrimmer.Visit(jToken);
    trimmed.ToString().Dump(nameof(PropertyNameTrimmer));
    var typeResolved = typeResolver.Visit(trimmed);
    typeResolved.ToString().Dump(nameof(TypeResolver));
}
```

So calling them in this order produces:

**Original**

```json
{
  "$t": "MyType",
  "User  ": "John",
  "Nested": {
    "$t": "OtherType",
    "   ZIP": 12345
  },
  "Numbers": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

**PropertyNameTrimmer** - whitespaces removed from property names

```json
{
  "$t": "MyType",
  "User": "John",
  "Nested": {
    "$t": "OtherType",
    "ZIP": 12345
  },
  "Numbers": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

**TypeResolver** - property names changed and types resolved

```json
{
  "$type": "MyType_resolved",
  "User": "John",
  "Nested": {
    "$type": "OtherType_resolved",
    "ZIP": 12345
  },
  "Numbers": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

---

How do you like this solution? Have I missed anything important (but null-checks) and can I improve this in any way?

Comment: Your visitor looks fine for what it does, but why rewrite property names instead of throwing an exception: `"Unknown property: 'User   ' at position ..."`? That also catches other problems like typos (`"Usr"`) and case differences (`"Zip"`), which are difficult to auto-correct due to ambiguity.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet yeah, it's a tough decision and I actually wasn't sure (and I'm still not) which one would be better, fixing or throwing exceptions. I was also going to allow dashes in property names that I would rewrite to `C#` valid names. Typos are difficult to handle anyway because if a property is optional it's hard to say whether it's something else or a typo. I guess I cannot eliminate all mistakes but at least reduce the probability. Btw, json is case-insensitive.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet for a complete validation I'll probably should use json-schema but I'm not sure about its license and whether I could use it at work... most likely not so I'm not even trying but even when using json-schema I still need to rewrite some parts of it ;-)

Comment: JSON isn't case-insensitive, but I see what you mean - Json.NET will try to find an exact match, but falls back to a case-insensitive check. Either way, it looks like passing a `JsonSerializerSettings` instance with `MissingMemberHandling` set to `Error` should do the trick.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet ok, it looks like you're correct with the [case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738375/235671), however, I'm glad nobody takes this rule serious, it'd break the entire internet if it suddenly would be respected - I find this rule is pretty stupid ;-]

Comment: That's JSON-RPC, not JSON itself.

Comment: A tiny improvement could be to insert a `case JValue value: result.Add(value); break;` in the loop in `VisitInternal(...)`

Comment: @HenrikHansen ah, right, good idea, this would help to avoid the unnecessary recursion and I see I can now throw away the `JValue` precondition. For `_resolveType` I use the `PrettyTypeResolver` from the [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205940/making-typenamehandling-in-json-net-more-convenient) question. This is the main purpose why I build all this ;-)

Comment: @HenrikHansen the most up-to-date and working code is [here](https://github.com/he-dev/Gunter/blob/dev/Gunter/src/Services/TestFileSerializer.cs#L69) where one of my tools loads json files using the new visitor.

Comment: @HenrikHansen sorry, for the confusion, I only abandoned the `JsonTextReader` for transforming, I moved it's logic to the `JsonVisitor` but both are using the `PrettyTypeResolver` as a dependency. This is the nice part when you have separated everything and can change one implementation and still reuse the others ;-)

Comment: @HenrikHansen the `JsonTextReader` and `JsonVisitor` should be just seen as tools for _scanning_ a json tree and/or modifying it. The actual work is done by other components. The disadvantage of the former approach was that you cannot chain them if you would like to do more then one thing.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I borrowed from both ideas - I'll keep fixing property names with leading/trailing whitespace but at the same time I created another vistor that will validate property names whether they are allowed or not and this one will throw exceptions if there is an unknown one - this way I can fix what is fixable and throw where nothing can be done - this time I can have a cake and eat it too ;-)