# Unquoting booleans, numbers, etc. in a JSON string

Tags: c#, performance, json, escaping

I have a method that takes a JSON string as input and "fixes" it. By that, I mean, that the JSON string comes in with all values quoted. My method un-quotes the values that shouldn't be quoted (i.e. true, false, numbers, {}, etc). The method was originally doing it by doing 4 string replaces (for the true / false, etc) and regex replace for the numbers. Kind of slow. So I re-wrote it with `StringBuilder`:

```
    protected static string FixupJson(string json)
    {
        if (json == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(json));

        int nLen = json.Length;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(nLen);

        for (int i = 0; i < nLen; i++)
        {
            char ch = json[i];

            if (ch == ':' && json[i+1] == ' ' && json[i + 2] == '\"')
            {
                int k = json.IndexOf('\"', i + 3);

                sb.Append(": ");

                string g = json.Substring(i + 3, k - i - 3);

                bool bQuote = true;

                if (g == "true" || g == "false" || g == "null" || g == "{}")
                    bQuote = false;
                else if (g == "NaN")
                    bQuote = true;
                else if (Double.TryParse(g, out double d))
                    bQuote = false;

                if (bQuote)
                    sb.Append('\"');

                sb.Append(g);

                if (bQuote)
                    sb.Append('\"');

                i = k;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(ch);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This got me a 35% improvement, but I want to see if there is a better approach or if I can get this faster. My first `StringBuilder` approach, instead of appending char by char would append chunks pulled out with `SubString()`. That was actually a lot slower then this version.

Yes, I understand the right way to do it would be to fix it at the source :), which I do control, but the way the json gets serialized out at the source, I don't know if the value needs to be quoted until the json is fully spit out (or at least until the value is fully spit out) as a single value can be a formatted string from multiple sources (i.e. "myVal": "(this part from one place)|(this part from another place))". So "fixing it there" would mean going from a single `String.Format()` for the entire json to a bunch of them for each value. Right now the JSON is "pre-rendered" (once) and passed into a `String.Format()` to fill in the values, so by fixing it there I'd have to go to a bunch of little `String.Format()`'s to format each value then pass it in to the big `String.Format()`… so I figure this is a decent compromise.

EDIT: Should handle any old json, but this was the one I was using in my test app in C# string format ready to paste :).

"{\r\n  \"xxx\": \"TRACE|1\",\r\n  \"Timestamp\": \"2019-01-01 12:44:36.529\",\r\n  \"Message\": {\r\n    \"a\": \"bbb\",\r\n    \"b1\": {\r\n      \"b2\": \"test2\",\r\n      \"b3\": \"Test1\",\r\n      \"b4\": \"true\",\r\n      \"b5\": \"178\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"ThreadId\": \"1\",\r\n  \"Exception\": \"{}\"\r\n}"

Comment: What would the typical json string look like?  What does the format method look like?  More eyes on it might see an even better solution.

Comment: @tinstaafl I added the one I am testing with. Basically just any old json. In this case, it should unquote the true, 178, 1 and {}. The json is generated dynamically at runtime based on a user template. My original design for performance was to parse the template once and build a "shell" string I could pass into String.Format() with as much of it pre-formatted as possible. For the above example it would start off as "{\r\n \"xxx\": \"{0}|{1}...

Comment: @tinstaafl make sense? Since the template is used over and over, I just pass in the cached string and the params to String.Format()… the problem with that is that for example, I don't know what the {0}|{1} is going to resolve to until the StringFormat is done, so I don't know if I need to quote it. Obviously in that case I would because of the | character :)… but it could just as easily be just {0} and then I wouldn't know what it is... so essentially I need to take the whole value (could be {0}{1} as a better example) at once to decide if I want to quote it.

Comment: This is a typical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I think you should have shown us how you create json first instead of trying to fix the serializer _bugs_ later ;-]

Answer (score 1):

I find your method for fixing *invalid* `JSON` is the worst possible because it treats `JSON` as a pure `string` and not a tree of properties/keys and values. This increases the possibility of changing values that might not be values at all. IMO the optimal approach would be to parse it with `JSON.NET` by using `JToken.Parse` and recreate the resulting tree with *correct* values.

You can take a look how it could be done [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208641/chaining-json-transformations-with-visitors) where I'm using the [Visitor Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html) to transform `JSON` too.

---

But honestly, unless you need to be able to read some old data, you should really fix the serializer so that it outputs valid `JSON` instead of trying to fix its *bugs* with even more dirty workarounds.