# Parse provided json, and in jObject find and convert all jToken.double types that have whole number value to long type

Tags: c#, tree, json

I wrote code sample below that is finding decimal values in jObject without '.' char, and convert them to long type. The issue is that it works for max jObject that contains two child jObjects.

```
public JObject ModifyDoubleIntegers(JObject objectToModify)
{
    JObject resultObjectModified = new JObject();
    foreach (var item in objectToModify)
    {
        if (item.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            var itemObject = (JObject)item.Value;
            var itemValues = new JObject();
            foreach (var childItem in itemObject)
            {
                if (childItem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    var grandChild = (JObject)childItem.Value;
                    var grandChildValues = new JObject();
                    foreach (var grandChildItem in grandChild)
                    {
                        if (grandChildItem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Float && !grandChildItem.Value.ToString().Contains('.'))
                        {
                            grandChildValues.Add(new JProperty(grandChildItem.Key, grandChildItem.Value.ToObject<long>()));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            grandChildValues.Add(new JProperty(grandChildItem.Key, grandChildItem.Value));
                        }
                    }
                    itemValues.Add(childItem.Key, grandChildValues);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (childItem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Float &&
                        !childItem.Value.ToString().Contains('.'))
                    {
                        itemValues.Add(new JProperty(childItem.Key, childItem.Value.ToObject<long>()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemValues.Add(new JProperty(childItem.Key, childItem.Value));
                    }
                }
            }
            resultObjectModified.Add(item.Key, itemValues);
        }
        else
        {
            if (item.Value.Type == JTokenType.Float && !item.Value.ToString().Contains('.'))
            {
                resultObjectModified.Add(new JProperty(item.Key, item.Value.ToObject<long>()));
            }
            else
            {
                resultObjectModified.Add(new JProperty(item.Key, item.Value));
            }
        }
    }
    return resultObjectModified;
}
```

json response from API:

```
{
    "id": "F32C93C0AD7B489DA904C10DAE724ED0",
    "name": "Pixar 99",
    "amount1": null,
    "currency": "ZAR",
    "referenceDate": "2019-04-05T00:00:00+00:00",
    "dealTeamLeadUser": null,
    "dealTeamSecondaryUser": null,
    "projectName": null,
    "region": {
      "id": "7680EEE333C648E49135AF52205F7DDC",
      "name": "Shared"
    },
    "priority": {
      "code": 3,
      "description": "Medium"
    },
    "sourceType": {
      "code": "FUNDINV",
      "description": "Fund (invested)"
    },
    "sourceContact": {
      "id": "22F2185C9B0E4D6A9945D00DAA1CA220",
      "firstName": "Ingeborg",
      "lastName": "Actili"
    },
    "sourceCompany": {
      "id": "95495010D5C1470F98184819263CD20C",
      "name": "Aquila LP"
    },
    "dealType": {
      "code": "FOF",
      "description": "Fund of funds"
    },
    "number": 65,
    "workflow": {
      "code": "22684BFAD6EC416A861E94ACD07421CF",
      "description": "2 - Fund of Private Equity"
    },
    "assignedToUser": {
      "id": "D260BCC5D72C4CBDA8A0003AAEA26120",
      "displayName": "AddTypeEmpty"
    },
    "assignedToGroup": null,
    "supervisorUser": {
      "id": "72BFD2F2725E488E8BB852673042735B",
      "displayName": "QA TEST eFront"
    },
    "supervisorGroup": null,
    "status": {
      "code": "FPE_4",
      "description": "4 - Detailed evaluation in progress (PE Fund)"
    },
    "nextStepDate": "2020-04-15T00:00:00+00:00",
    "companyInfo": null,
    "closingDate": "2021-04-16T00:00:00+00:00",
    "expectedFinalCloseDate": "2022-04-06T00:00:00+00:00",
    "ourCommitment": 12000000,
    "targetIrr": 0.14,
    "targetTvpi": 3,
    "fundInfo": {
      "id": "346A51E0399341ABACFEE92F5B40A9BA",
      "region": {
        "id": "7680EEE333C648E49135AF52205F7DDC",
        "name": "Shared"
      },
      "name": "Antlia Opportunities Fund IV LLP",
      "shortName": "Antlia IV",
      "status": {
        "code": 301,
        "description": "Prospect Invested Fund"
      },
      "legalForm": {
        "code": "ZAF-LLP",
        "description": "ZAF - LLP - Limited Liability Partnership"
      },
      "nature": {
        "code": "50000000",
        "description": "50 - Telecommunication Services"
      },
      "category": null,
      "stage": {
        "code": "PE_MEZZ",
        "description": "PE - Mezzanine Capital"
      },
      "geography": {
        "code": "AFRICA_SOUTHERN",
        "description": "Southern Africa"
      },
      "vintageYear": 2011,
      "startDate": "2011-03-16T00:00:00+00:00",
      "closeDate": "2011-04-30T00:00:00+00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "contractDate": null,
      "mangtFeesOutsideCommitment": false,
      "endInvestDate": "2015-04-30T00:00:00+00:00",
      "endPlannedDate": "2020-04-30T00:00:00+00:00",
      "endAddPlannedDate": null,
      "investmentPeriod": null,
      "fundDuration": null,
      "additionalYears": null,
      "clawback": false,
      "catchup": null,
      "managementFeesPercent": 0.01,
      "managementFeesPercent1": 0.01,
      "managementFeesMore": null,
      "managementFeesPolicy": null,
      "country": {
        "code": "ZA",
        "description": "South Africa"
      },
      "currency": "ZAR",
      "carriedInterest": 0.15,
      "carriedPerDeal": false,
      "hurdleRate": 0.08,
      "catchupRate": 0.02,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "investmentPolicy": null,
      "distributionPolicy": null,
      "revenueDistribution": null,
      "secondHurdle": 0.03,
      "hurdleDescription": null,
      "secondCarried": 0.19,
      "carriedDescription": null,
      "managementFrequency": {
        "code": "QUATERLY"
      },
      "fundGroupBy": {
        "id": "FC4362360C8F4FF59D6161241E10110E",
        "name": "eFront Parallel Fund B"
      },
      "managementCompany": {
        "id": "FE5A9AAAFDE44E01BEA2AF85DF449855",
        "managementCompanyId": null,
        "name": "Antlia (Pty) Ltd"
      },
      "otherFund": {
        "id": "104CB83F393D409D8B3DED9FDCB8EEC9",
        "region": {
          "id": "7680EEE333C648E49135AF52205F7DDC",
          "name": "Shared"
        },
        "name": {
          "id": "346A51E0399341ABACFEE92F5B40A9BA",
          "name": "Antlia Opportunities Fund IV LLP"
        },
        "mngtFeesBeforeInvestment": null,
        "beforeMngtFeesBase": {
          "code": "COMMITMENT",
          "description": "Commitment"
        },
        "mngtFeesAfterInvestment": null,
        "afterMngtFeesBase": {
          "code": "NAV",
          "description": "NAV"
        },
        "feeOffset": null,
        "feeOffsetDescription": "1,00%",
        "hurdleBase": {
          "code": "1",
          "description": "Called capital"
        },
        "hurdleType": null,
        "size": 4500000000,
        "extensionMngtFeeBase": null,
        "minSize": null,
        "maxSize": null,
        "firstCloseSize": null
      },
      "hedgeFund": {
        "id": "2B1B5B97A441493BBD62D560C3E64CB7",
        "region": {
          "id": "7680EEE333C648E49135AF52205F7DDC",
          "name": "Shared"
        },
        "name": {
          "id": "346A51E0399341ABACFEE92F5B40A9BA",
          "name": "Antlia Opportunities Fund IV LLP"
        },
        "minimumInvestment": null,
        "managementFee": null,
        "redemptionFee": null,
        "incentiveFee": null,
        "otherFees": null,
        "managementFeeHelp": null,
        "redemptionFeeHelp": null,
        "incentiveFeeHelp": null,
        "otherFeesHelp": null,
        "admissionDates": null,
        "subscriptionFreq": null,
        "subscriptionFreqHelp": null,
        "redemptionFreq": null,
        "redemptionFreqHelp": null,
        "redemptionNoticeDays": null,
        "redemptionNotice": null,
        "redemptionPayout": null,
        "highWaterMarkText": null,
        "sidePocket": null,
        "sidePocketText": null,
        "newIssues": null,
        "newIssuesText": null,
        "reportingPeriod": null,
        "reportingStyle": null,
        "fundAssets": null,
        "domicile": null,
        "highWaterMark": null,
        "hurdleRate": null,
        "leverage": null,
        "crystallization": null,
        "hurdleRateHelp": null,
        "leverageHelp": null,
        "crystallizationHelp": null,
        "lockup": null,
        "lockupPeriod": null,
        "lockupPeriodHelp": null,
        "number1": null,
        "fiscalDay1": null,
        "fiscalMonth1": null,
        "initialVami": null,
        "benchmark1": null,
        "benchmark2": null
      },
      "firmContact": {
        "id": "CC9D6D4E77684E4D82314FA70705BF4E",
        "name": "Rawlinson, Anthony B."
      },
      "offerCoInvestment": null,
      "gpCommitment": 0.03,
      "mngFeesPercentExtension": null,
      "feeOffset": null,
      "carryEscrow": 0.23
    },
    "keyFigures": null,
    "investment": null,
    "comments": null,
    "description": null
  }
```

Comment: Hi. What version of the Newtonsoft library you use? Also, does your code compile?

Comment: _and it works for max jObject that contains two child jObjects_ - why is this an issue? We'll also need some samples. Could you create a console app (or something) demonstrating how this code works?

Comment: also check this out for recursively finding leaf nodes in this monstrously written API (https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Iae0V)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I have just noticed that this is not at all recursive... why are calling it like that?

Comment: @dfhwze It uses 11.0, and yes it compiles and it is working.

Comment: @t3chb0t I've added json response that I am going through, after parsing it with jObject.Parse.

Answer (score 2):

### Proposed Solution

```
public static JObject ModifyDoubleIntegers(JObject source) {
        if (source == null) return null;
        var target = new JObject(source);
        var properties = target.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(
            x => x.Type == JTokenType.Float).Select(x => x.Parent).OfType<JProperty>();
        foreach (var property in properties.Where(x
            => Regex.IsMatch(x.Value.ToObject<string>(), @"^\d*$")))
        {
            property.Value = property.Value.ToObject<long>();
        }
        return target;
    }
```

---

### Remark

When parsing the sample json file you provided, all integers were parsed as `JTokenType.Integer` and all floats as `JTokenType.Float`, so I feel this entire problem is mute. Everything gets parsed correctly by calling `JObject.Parse(json)`.

> How did you end up having integer values in a `JTokenType.Float`?

---

### Review

First of all, you don't need to loop `n` levels deep. There is a convenient method `JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf` that does the trick for you. I also changed the variable names to more common names.

> ```
> public JObject ModifyDoubleIntegers(JObject objectToModify)
> {
>     JObject resultObjectModified = new JObject();
>     foreach (var item in objectToModify)
>     {
>         ..
> ```

```
 public static JObject ModifyDoubleIntegers(JObject source) {
        if (source == null) return null;
        var target = new JObject(source);
        var properties = target.DescendantsAndSelf();
        ..
```

---

Now, to change the `float` values to `long`, you need to obtain all *descendants* of type `JTokenType.Float` and select their *parent* `JProperty`.

> ```
> foreach (var grandChildItem in grandChild)
>  {
>      if (grandChildItem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Float))
>      {
>           ..
> ```

```
var properties = target.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(
     x => x.Type == JTokenType.Float).Select(x => x.Parent).OfType<JProperty>();
```

---

The last step is to change from `float` to `long`. I would not filter on `Contains('.')`, since this depends on your thread's `CultureInfo`. At my computer, I would have to check on `Contains(',')`. [after remarks OP] We should use a context-free check on `float`. The best I can come up with is `Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^\d*$")`.

> ```
>  if (grandChildItem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Float 
>            && !grandChildItem.Value.ToString().Contains('.'))      
>   {
>       grandChildValues.Add(new JProperty(
>            grandChildItem.Key, grandChildItem.Value.ToObject<long>()));      
>   }
> ```

```
foreach (var property in properties.Where(x
     => Regex.IsMatch(x.Value.ToObject<string>(), @"^\d*$")))
{ 
     property.Value = property.Value.ToObject<long>();
}
```

---

Comment: It is indeed a good solution, but still not working well. There are differences for all the float type JTokens with values other than integer. They are cutoff after the '.'  ex:  **"hurdleRate": 0.08** becomes **"hurdleRate": 0** . That was the reason I was checking for the '.' when I find the **jTokenType.Float**

Comment: @miskegm I am a bit confused on what exactly you want. I have provided a solution that does exactly the same as yours. Could you please specify what you expect from the code, that would make things a bit easier to follow :)

Comment: @miskegm I think I get it now, you want all Integer values that are stored in a float to be stored a long. I will adapt my answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly that, int values stored in float to be stored a long. It works like a charm now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When parsing json response from server, the jToken float values like amount = 13000, becomes amount = 13000.0, so that is the reason fot this modification I am doing.

Comment: @miskegm Then perhaps the regex should become @"^\d*([,.][0])?$". Else I think 13000.0 will remain so.

Comment: I prefer a visitor like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208641/chaining-json-transformations-with-visitors) one to traverse and modify the tree similar to the expression-visitor and leave the original tree untouched. Nicely extendable ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t When building an API for JToken-processing, I would definately go with the visitor and/or listener approaches. For this use-case, I don't mind a simple Linq approach :-)